# Write to file after async tasks complete

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I wrote the following code to create an object with KEYS set to commented headers and VALUES set to the files that share these headers.  If there is no header the file name gets written to a file.  I would like to write this header object to file but it's being written before the object completes.  I understand why this is happening but I can't seem to fix the issue.  Here is the code for writing the object to file:

```
stringObj = JSON.stringify(allHeaders, null, 4);
    fs.writeFile(currentHeads, stringObj, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
    console.log('Complete!');
```

And here is the rest of the script:

```
    "use strict";

var fs = require('fs'),
    dive = require('dive'),
    subdirs = require('subdirs'),
    cpFile = __dirname + "/" + "header.txt",
    noCopy = __dirname + "/" + "noCopyright.txt",
    currentHeads = __dirname + "/" + "currentHeaders.txt",
    re = /(\/\*(?:(?!\*\/).|[\n\r])*\*\/)/, // matches first multi-line comment
    walkDir,
    allHeaders = {},
    stringObj,
    top;


fs.readFile(cpFile, 'utf8', function(err, copyRight) {
    subdirs(__dirname, 1, function(err, dirs) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        dirs.forEach(function(dir) {
            if (dir.match(/.*\/src$/)) {
                dive(dir, { all: false }, function(err, file) {
                    if (err) {
                        return console.log(err);
                    }
                    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
                        if (err) {
                            return console.log(err);
                        }
                        if (data.match(re)) {
                            top = data.match(re);
                            if (allHeaders[top[0]]) {
                                allHeaders[top[0]].push(file);
                            } else {
                                allHeaders[top[0]] = [file];
                            }
                        } else {
                            fs.appendFile(noCopy, file + "\n", function(err) {
                                if (err) {
                                    return console.log(err);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It still requires further refactoring but should give you the idea:

```
function processDir(dir, callback) {
   dive(dir, {all: false}, function (err, file) {
      if (err) {
        return callback(err);
      }

      fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', callback);
   });
}

fs.readFile(cpFile, 'utf8', function(err, copyRight) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);

  subdirs(__dirname, 1, function (err, dirs) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);

    async.each(dirs, function (dir, next) {
      if (!dir.match(/.*\/src$/)) return next();

      processDir(dir, function(err, data) {
        if (err) return next(err);

        if (!data.match(re)) {
          return fs.appendFile(noCopy, file + "\n", next);
        }

        top = data.match(re);
        if (allHeaders[top[0]]) {
          allHeaders[top[0]].push(file);
        } else {
          allHeaders[top[0]] = [file];
        }
        return next();
      });
    }, function (err) {
      if (err) return console.error(err);

      stringObj = JSON.stringify(allHeaders, null, 4);
      fs.writeFile(currentHeads, stringObj, function(err) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);

        console.log('Complete!');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to spell this out for me!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that you use asynchronous function (dive) inside synchronous (dirs.forEach) and the next function in you code (which writes allHeaders to file) being executed earlier then all directives are actually processed.

To fix this you can use 'async' module for example:

```
async.each(dirs, function(dir, next) {
  // process dir here, in case of error call return next(err), otherwise call return next();
}, function(err) {
   // process err somehow
   // if there is no error, all directives are processed, write allHeaders to file

   stringObj = JSON.stringify(allHeaders, null, 4);
   fs.writeFile(currentHeads, stringObj, function(err) {
     if (err) {
        console.log(err);
     }

     console.log('Complete!');
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look but it seems that the function containing the write to file never gets run.  I think the async.each is a good change anyways.

Comment: Make sure you call next() function for each directive inside async.each()